# VHDL types mismatch during simulation MODELSIM

Tags: error-handling, vhdl

I am getting this error :

```
# Loading std.standard
# Loading ieee.std_logic_1164(body)
# Loading ieee.numeric_std(body)
# Loading work.acc(behavioralreg)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_arith(body)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_unsigned(body)
# Loading work.alu(arc)
# Loading work.ar(behavioralreg)
# Loading work.controlunit(arc)
# Loading work.ir(behavioralreg)
# Loading work.memory(behv)
# Loading work.pc(behavioralreg)
# Loading work.processor(arc)
```

-----------NOW COMES ERROR -------------

```
# ** Failure: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "address".
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /processor/memmap File: C:/Users/dell/Desktop/PROESSORS/VHDL Codes_1/333CO10_Proc.vhdl/memory.vhd Line: 10
# ** Error: (vsim-3733) C:/Users/dell/Desktop/PROESSORS/VHDL Codes_1/333CO10_Proc.vhdl/processor.vhd(187): No default binding for component at 'memmap'.
#  (Generic 'words' is not on the entity.)
#         Region: /processor/memmap
# ** Error: (vsim-3733) C:/Users/dell/Desktop/PROESSORS/VHDL Codes_1/333CO10_Proc.vhdl/processor.vhd(187): No default binding for component at 'memmap'.
#  (Generic 'bits' is not on the entity.)
#         Region: /processor/memmap
# Fatal error in Process rea at C:/Users/dell/Desktop/PROESSORS/VHDL Codes_1/333CO10_Proc.vhdl/memory.vhd line 50
#  while elaborating region: /processor/memmap
# Fatal error in Process line__201 at C:/Users/dell/Desktop/PROESSORS/VHDL Codes_1/333CO10_Proc.vhdl/processor.vhd line 201
#  while elaborating region: /processor
```

what is error ? i have checked it many times but not getting the wrong point. I am a beginner in VHDL .

my code :

```
library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity processor is
end processor;

architecture arc of processor is
---some code
component memory

generic( bits : INTEGER:=8;
         words :INTEGER:=256);  

port (  
    enable      :   in std_logic;
        read        :   in std_logic;
        write       :   in std_logic;
        address :   in INTEGER range 0 to words-1;
        data_in :   in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_out:   out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end component;
--some code
signal MEMenable        : std_logic:='0';
signal  MEMread     :   std_logic:='0';
signal  MEMwrite        :   std_logic:='0';
signal MEMaddr  :    INTEGER range 0 to 255;
signal  MEMdata_in  :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):="0000000000000000";
signal  MEMdata_out:     std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):="0000000000000000";
signal clk: bit ;
  signal clocktime :integer range 0 to 10 :=0;
  signal rst : bit :='0';
--now PORT MAPPING COMPONENTS-----
begin
--- some code
MEMmap: memory port map(    
        enable=>MEMenable   ,
        read=>MEMread   ,
        write=>MEMwrite,
        address=>MEMaddr    ,
        data_in=>MEMdata_in ,
        data_out=>MEMdata_out
);
--- some code
```

and memory is :

```
library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity memory is
port (
    enable      :   in std_logic;
        read        :   in std_logic;
        write   :   in std_logic;
        address :   in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        data_in :   in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_out:   out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end memory;

architecture behv of memory is          

  type ram_type is array (0 to 255) of 
                std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal tmp_ram: ram_type;

begin

    writ: process(enable, read, address, data_in)
    begin
    ---some code
    end process;
end behv;
```

all files : if you want full codes, please ask me.

Comment: For example the port declaration for memory is address :   in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); while the component declaration is address :   in INTEGER range 0 to words-1; and the map is address=>MEMaddr with the declaration signal MEMaddr  :    INTEGER range 0 to 255;.  Your entity memory doesn't appear to match the component declaration of your usage.

Answer (score 1):

The component "memory" you refer in your architecture needs to have exactly the same ports types, which is not the case in your code.

In the component, the adress is typed as "integer range ..." while the memory entity uses plain std_logic_vector...